# Вывод баннеров , как сортировать

Tags: php, sql

Добавляю 2 баннера в базу, у них по 0 просмотров.
Выводятся они сейчас по 1, сортируются по просмотрам

```
ORDER BY `shows` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Вывод 1 ого баннера - 1 просмотр добавляет

все прекрасно работает, но если я добавлю баннер еще 1 , у него будет 0 просмотров, и он будет постоянно показываться, до тех пор, пока не наберет такое же кол-во просмотров как и у братьев.

Вот собственно и возник вопрос, как же их выводить , по какому критерию сортировать, что бы они выводились поочередно?

Answer (score 1):

добавьте в конце запроса `ORDER BY RAND()` - запрос выберет записи по рендому

Comment: Я бы сортировал по shows * RAND()

Comment: а чем это будет лучше?

Comment: тем, что каждый раз Вам запрос вернет разные записи, ну правда не поочередно а случайным образом (по рендому)